# User created function doesn't work when trying invoking from excel cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have below given function declared in VBA of excel. On trying invoking the same from excel one of the cells it shows 0.

```
Function AddNumber(num1 As Integer, num2 As Integer) As Integer
    Dim sumValue As Integer
    sumValue = num1 + num2
End Function
```

Cells function invocation:

```
=AddNumber(2,5)
```

Result:
0

Error on evaluation:

```
#NAME?
```

Answer (score 0):

In VBA, in order to return a value from a function you need to assign the return value to the function name itself.

Also, mark your function as `Public`, so it will be visible when you call it from your sheet.

Your function should therefore become:

```
Public Function AddNumber(num1 As Integer, num2 As Integer) As Integer
    AddNumber = num1 + num2
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response w0lf but unfortuntely the change suggested by you still doesn't work for me. Do i need to save the workspace & expect the change?

Comment: Try entering the formula in another cell, to make sure the `#NAME?` value is not cached or something.

Comment: @Ashish Also, please note the edit to my answer: the function should be marked `Public`

Comment: The function must be in a normal module and you must have macros enabled.

Comment: Many thanks w0lf, addition of keyword Public makes it work perfectly. I could start thinking of coding a bigger one now. I appreciate your competency in this.